# No scrollbar, navigation disappeared

Tags: html, css

I uploaded a modified version of my website earlier. It seems to work fine on my computer, but then I check my laptop downstairs, (small screen), and there doesn't appear to be a scroll bar to scroll down and see the navigation, so you're just left with a big image that doesn't do anything.

It's http://www.peach-designs.com - it'll only be up for a short time though as it doesn't yet work on small screens.

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Comment: Needs more info: What browser, what resolution... Works fine for me in Chrome and IE on a small resolution, although in IE, the right hand side is weird when scrolling in *any* resolution

Comment: On me 10 inch screen in chrome I see your problem. The navigation seem to be behind the picture instead of under it. I dont know why

Comment: what do you mean 'wierd'? my current resolution is 1920 x 1080, and it works on all browsers, then i go downstairs on my laptop - on both firefox and IE in 1024 x 768 and it the problem described above happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I view the site in Chrome, the image covers the navigation because of the z-index ordering.  Removing the z-index from `#slider` and the `ul` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: hi, i don't think i have a z index...what stylesheet did this show up on?

Comment: so i can just override this by setting z:index to none in slider and ul?

Comment: Or just remove the z-index property altogether.

Comment: well there isn't an inline style in the html, so i don't know where this is coming from.

Comment: Hmm... I viewed the source this time, and the inline styles aren't showing up.  However, I do see them as inline styles when inspecting the document.  `jCarouselLite` must be inserting those styles.